# transformJackWithJackForDebug takes too long to compile

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have gradle 3.3 which I can not update because of the complexity of dependencies. Is there any way to eliminate `transformJackWithJackForDebug` process from the compilation.

[image]